# Bad Request Error When Using Async Await in a for loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to get the async await in the for loop to run, but I keep getting a 400 error(bad request). When I expressly replace the query x with a known value, the code runs as expected.

```
const expected_res = (async function(param){
   const response = await fetch("https://apione.com?x="+ param)
   const data = await response.json()
  ....

})(param).then( (results)=>{

 ...
  return result 

}).then(async (data)=>{
 //Note:  data is an array

for( const id of data){
    //Note: id is of type string  console.log( typeof id, id instanceof String) => string, false 
     const response = await fetch("https://apitwo.com?x="+ id) // this is where the error occurs
     const data = await response.json()
   }
 })
```

Comment: can you provide information about var called IDs? Looks like (id of IDs) is not a string which causes url to have `?x=[object Object]` something of that sort.

Comment: @Abhilash My bad. The variable ID should be data instead. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Not specifically your problem but please declare your variables locally, ie `for(let id of data)`

Comment: How about adding `console.log('id', typeof id, id)` to inspect the actual value rather than guessing it's appropriate to use in a query string

Comment: @Phil It's a string and data is an array containing strings

Comment: try `console.log(id.toString())` as first line inside `for(let id of data)`. It should show you the exact value which will be used in the query param. Also make use of Network Inspector to see what value it is.

Comment: It could be a string but not a desirable one to be sent in URL.

Comment: @Abhilash You're onto something. I've tried using templating ${id} but still the same error. When I expressly place the value of id in quotes the code runs. Example: "2389283". But when I use id.toString()  or ${id} it doesn't work

Comment: We keep asking you to add some console debugging so what are the results of those? I'd be particularly interested in `console.log('id', typeof id, id)`. What sort of values for `id` are causing the request to fail?

Comment: @Phil console.log( id, typeof id, id instanceof String) => 407b58224b9e4c0580d653e06930a644, string, false

Answer (score 0):

When creating path segments or query parameters, you should always make sure they're encoded correctly.

You can wrap the values in [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). For query parameters, you can also use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) for a more modern approach.

```js
const query = new URLSearchParams({
  startTime: 8, // no idea where this is supposed to come from
  endTime: 10   // nor this
})
const response = await fetch(`https://apitwo.com/api/${encodeURIComponent(id)}?${query}`)
```

Comment: Sorry, the request is supposed to be sent like this : apitwo.com/api/407b58224b9e4c0580d653e06930a644?startTime=8&endTime=10. How do I extract only id from  query object? I get undefined when I try ${query['id']} Same for ${query.id}

Comment: @idiot it would really help if your question matched reality

Comment: @idiot I've updated my answer to match your **new** requirements

Comment: I found this error in chrome dev tools. ReferenceError: browser is not defined. I paused on the 2nd fetch. I'm hardcoding the start and end times for now

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Vaue of id as i step through. id: "407b58224b9e4c0580d653e06"